# Orange Import dataset which has the feature on rows and instances on the columns

Tags: orange

How to import a flipped dataset into the Orange 3.26? By flipped dataset I mean a dataset which has the features as rows and the instances as columns.

I tried to transpose the data after imported but this transpose the dataset and took the rows of the transposed dataset as features. So Orange keep taking the instances as features.

Watch the next screen capture. Each of the H's are instances, but Orange already read them as features.
[image]

So I tried to transpose the dataset

[image]

But that didn't help. The dataset was transposed but we keep the instances (H's) as features. Check the red underline, it says that the rows are features.
[image]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your raw dataset? I guess your dataset looks like this: Person 1, Person 2, ... Person 48 as columns and Feature 1, Feature 2, ... Feature n as rows. You then want to transpose your data, not pivot. (Pivot is more like taking a single categorical feature and expanding it into columns.)